# Reading CGI POST data the most efficient way

Tags: c, parsing, post, cgi, storage

I'm in great need of a way to dig through potentially huge amounts of CGI supplied POST data.

With reading the GET data it's no big deal, as I can just re-request the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable as often as I want, but with POST data which is supplied via `stdin`. I can only read it in once and have to store it somewhere.

My current method consists of reading the whole bunch of POST data inside a temporary file which will be removed when the program exits and scan through it to find the keys I want to fin.
In the GET parsing approach I could just strtok() over the QUERY_STRING because GET data has pretty low limits so it's safe to be fetched inside RAM, but the POST data can be anything from empty to "name=Bob" to a 4 Gigabye movie file.

So, here's my current approach:

```
int get_post_data(const char *s_key, char *target, size_t target_size)
{
   FILE *tmp;
   int ret_val = -1;

   /* postdata_temp = global variable containing the temporary file name */
   if ((tmp = fopen(postdata_tempfile, "r")) == NULL)
      return -1;
   else
   {
      char *buffer = NULL;
      char *temp_buffer = NULL;
      int buffer_size;
      int i;

      if ((buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE)) == NULL)
         return -1;

      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(BUFFER_SIZE));
      buffer_size = BUFFER_SIZE;

      for (i = 0;; i++)
      {
         int c = fgetc(tmp);

         if ((c == '&') || feof(tmp))
         {
            char *key = strtok(buffer, "=");
            char *val = strtok(NULL, "");            

            if (key)
            {
               if (strcmp(s_key, key) == 0)
               {
                  if (val)
                  {
                     strncpy(target, val, target_size);
                     ret_val = strlen(val);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     target = NULL;
                     ret_val = 0;
                  }

                  break;
               }
            }

            if (feof(tmp))
               break;

            memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
            i = -1; /* because it will be 0 when the fgetc() is called the 
                     * next time */
         }
         else
         {
            if (!(i < buffer_size))
            {
               buffer_size += BUFFER_SIZE;

               if ((temp_buffer = realloc(buffer, buffer_size)) == NULL)
               {
                  free(temp_buffer);
                  free(buffer);
                  target = NULL;

                  return -1;
               }
               else
                  buffer = temp_buffer;
            }

            buffer[i] = c;
         }

      }

      free(buffer);

      // printf("Final buffer size: %d<br />\n", buffer_size);
   }

   fclose(tmp);

   return ret_val;
}
```

This does work, I can call `get_post_data("user_password", pass, sizeof(pass));`, check for the return value (<0 = error, =0 = key exists but value is NULL, >0 = data length), but it seems too obese. I mean.. huge IO overhead for every single POST parameter I want to search just to not have the whole string inside my RAM for potentially large files being uploaded?

What does Stackoverflow think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid loading a big file into RAM, you could use a memory mapped file - not portable, but it's the right way to do it. If your platform is POSIX you could use `mmap()` for this.

By the way I didn't fully read or test your code but I would wonder whether using `strtok()` is the right thing to do because it destroys the data as it goes. I'd also wonder about using `str...()` functions if your data is maybe a binary file, but I don't know how the CGI part works so you might be right there.

Comment: The data arrives as "key=value" and I use `strtok()` to cut apart key and value. Only the value is binary in practice and will be handed unmodified to the caller :)

Comment: @LukeN: Did any of this help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to just reject POST requests larger than a set limit, say 2MB.

That way:

- You have a manageable-sized block of data to work with.
- You prevent malicious 4GB POST requests.

Comment: I try not to limit what my program can accept. In this particular case (text articles) 2 MB is way enough, but I write my modules in a way that enables me to use them in any case, like file uploads where 2 MB is a drop in a bucket. :)